# Jquery Slide Toggle not triggering

Tags: jquery

I am trying out jquery slidetoggle but I'm having issues trying to run it. Please check on the fiddle provided. https://jsfiddle.net/2yL2Q/63/

When I click on the flip class, its not doing anything.

Code Sample

```
<div class="some-div">
<div class="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
</div>
<div class="panel">Hello world!</div>

<div class="some-div">
<div class="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
</div>
<div class="panel">Hello world!</div>

<div class="some-div">
<div class="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
</div>
<div class="panel">Hello world!</div>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".some-div .flip").click(function () {
        $(this).next('.panel').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to select a `.panel` element that is a following adjacent sibling to the clicked `.flip` element. Your markup would need to look like this in order for your jQuery to work:

```
<div class="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div class="panel">Hello world!</div>
```

Since those elements aren't siblings in the HTML you provided, you need to traverse the DOM and select the parent element. Simply use the [`.parent()` method](https://api.jquery.com/parent/):

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/qecp3joL/)

```
$(".some-div .flip").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().next('.panel').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Alternatively, if the depth/nesting of the elements varies, you could also use the [`.closest()` method](https://api.jquery.com/closest/):

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/6mwddrqu/)

```
$(".some-div .flip").click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.some-div').next('.panel').slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Got it. May i know where can I find this doc?

Comment: @DroidBeginner Yep--I just linked to both of the mentioned methods in the answer. You can look the the jQuery API documentation to see all the methods - http://api.jquery.com/